# Set a breakpoint on GDB entry point for stripped PIE binaries without disabling ASLR

Tags: debugging, gdb, elf

Given a position-independent, statically-linked, stripped binary, there does not appear to be a way in GDB to set a breakpoint at the entry point without disabling ASLR.

- `break start` and similar functions do not work, because there is no symbolic information
- `set stop-on-solib-events 1` does not work as the binary is not dynamically linked
- `break *0xdeadbeef` for the entry point does not work, as the entry point is unresolved until the binary starts
- `catch load` does not work, as it does not load any libraries
- `start` does not work, as `main` is not defined and no libraries are loaded

Without patching the binary, what mechanism can I use to break at the first instruction executed?

### Possible?

Since a now-deleted response to the question said that a PIE statically-linked binary is impossible, a trivial example is the linker itself.

It is statically linked.

```
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
    statically linked
```

It is executable.

```
$ strace /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
execve("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so", ["/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so"], [/* 96 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x7ff787b3d000
writev(2, [{"Usage: ld.so [OPTION]... EXECUTA"..., 1373}], 1Usage: ld.so [OPTION]... EXECUTABLE-FILE [ARGS-FOR-PROGRAM...]
```

It is position-independent.

```
$ readelf -h /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so | grep DYN
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
```

### Solutions

It looks like this can be done with Python by utilizing some of the events made available: http://asciinema.org/a/19078

However, I'd like a native-GDB solution.

A successful solution will break at `_start` in ld.so when executed directly without disabling ASLR.  It should look something like this:

```
sh $ strip -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so -o ld.so
sh $ gdb ./ld.so
(gdb) $ set disable-randomization off
(gdb) $ <your magic commands>
(gdb) $ x/i $pc
=> 0x7f9ba515d2d0:     mov    rdi,rsp
(gdb) $ info proc map
process 10432
Mapped address spaces:

        Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
    0x7f9ba515c000     0x7f9ba517f000    0x23000        0x0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so 
    0x7f9ba537e000     0x7f9ba5380000     0x2000    0x22000 /lib/x86_64- linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
    0x7f9ba5380000     0x7f9ba5381000     0x1000        0x0 
    0x7fffc34c7000     0x7fffc38ca000   0x403000        0x0 [stack]
    0x7fffc398b000     0x7fffc398d000     0x2000        0x0 [vdso]
0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0 [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint in the GOT section ? For example, on `_libc_start_main()`.

Comment: "position-independent, statically-linked" -- There is no GOT.

Comment: My bad... I read too quickly. Sorry.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483544/stopping-at-the-first-machine-code-instruction-in-gdb

Answer (score 24, accepted):

UPDATE: GDB 8.1 has a `starti` command, as mentioned below by /u/ruslan

Setting a breakpoint on an unmapped address before starting the target process does this, effectively.  It's not correct functionality, but rather a side-effect of the failure to set the breakpoint.

```
(gdb) break *0
Breakpoint 1 at 0x0
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/ld.so 
Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x7faae3a25cd0:      mov    rdi,rsp
```

Answer (score 12):

Starting with GDB 8.1, there's a special command for this: `starti`. Example GDB session:

```
$ gdb /bin/true
Reading symbols from /bin/true...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) starti
Starting program: /bin/true 

Program stopped.
0xf7fdd800 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) x/5i $pc
=> 0xf7fdd800 <_start>: mov    eax,esp
   0xf7fdd802 <_start+2>:       call   0xf7fe2160 <_dl_start>
   0xf7fdd807 <_dl_start_user>: mov    edi,eax
   0xf7fdd809 <_dl_start_user+2>:       call   0xf7fdd7f0
   0xf7fdd80e <_dl_start_user+7>:       add    ebx,0x1f7e6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define gdb function to break on first argument of libc_star_main. The first si/ni is to load libc itself. Put it in your .gdbinit file.

```
define bmain
    si
    ni
    b __libc_start_main
    c
    b *($rdi)
    c
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this and thought I would add a bit.

If you want to stop at the entry point of a stripped, dynamically-linked program, I recommend the following procedure.

1. Start GDB with the file.
2. Start the program with `starti` so that the loader maps it into memory.
   (By default GDB turns off ASLR for your program, but this method will work either way.)
3. Use `info file` to get the address of the entry point.  This will show virtual addresses *after start* (that's why we used `starti` first).
4. Find the entry point and set a breakpoint at that address.
5. Run `cont` to get to the breakpoint.

```
$ gdb /usr/bin/ls
(gdb) starti
(gdb) info file
...
Local exec file:
    `/usr/bin/ls', file type elf64-x86-64.
    Entry point: 0x55555555a7d0
...
(gdb) b *0x55555555a7d0
(gdb) cont
...
Breakpoint 1, 0x000055555555a7d0 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/i $rip
=> 0x55555555a7d0:  endbr64
```

Now, if you want `main` on Linux, step ahead through the disassembly until you find out how `rdi` is being set (assuming the usual `crt0.o` has been linked to start the C runtime).

```
(gdb) 
   0x55555555a7f1:  lea    rdi,[rip+0xffffffffffffe5f8]        # 0x555555558df0
```

Ah ha!  We can find `main` (even without any symbols) at 0x555555558df0.

```
(gdb) b *0x555555558df0
(gdb) cont
```

Now you are at `main`.
Leaving this here in case someone else comes along with the same question.